# Kubernetes: Which Ingress Controller are permitted to use for grpc service without TLS?

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed nginx as ingress controller for grpc service in the Kubernetes. Everything works fine with a TLS certificate which is required by nginx ingress controller. This means that I must refactor the code of grpc client to use secure channel. There are lots of work to do and unnecessary.
I wonder if there is any ingress controller are permitted to use for grpc service without TLS

Comment: While technically possible to do http2 without tls, very few tools implement it and it is firmly not recommended.

Comment: please follow [Feature Request: support gRPC over plaintext (non-TLS)](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3897)